# Change sorting feature to area

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, array

I have a table of attributes with polygons, from the area data I sort from largest to smallest, and when using the command `@row_number`, he writes the order in which the polygons were created. I want to know how to change the classification of features to the size of the area and then make the count from largest to smallest?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use use the Field Calculator to create a new field using the size of the polygons to sort your objects.

This is the expression that you can use:

```
array_find(array_sort(array_agg("field_name")), "field_name")+1
```

In your case it will be:

```
array_find(array_sort(array_agg("ha")), "ha")+1
```